# Decorator to allow only integer values from postman in Python Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-views

I am new to Python Django and am trying to write a decorator which allows only integer values from postman (my function is about take particular student details against roll number). If a string is passed, it should raise an exception.

Here's my code so far:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def select_student(request):
    print(request.data)
    b={}
    data_id = request.data['id']
    data = Marks.objects.select_related('Students').filter(id=data_id)
    for i in data:
        b['Name'] = i.Students.Name b['English']=i.English
        b['Tamil'] = i.Tamil b['Maths']=i.Maths
    return JsonResponse(b, safe=False)
```

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Please post any code that demonstrates reasonable effort and shows what you have tried so far. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @api_view(['POST'])
def select_student(request):
    print(request.data)
    b={}
    data_id=request.data['id']
    data = Marks.objects.select_related('Students').filter(id=data_id)
    for i in data:
        b['Name']=i.Students.Name
        b['English']=i.English
        b['Tamil']=i.Tamil
        b['Maths']=i.Maths
    return JsonResponse(b,safe=False)   Above is the code  if it is not clear please revert